# What happens when you place a Ghost Ward beyond the Sightstone's limit?

Tags: league-of-legends

The new [Sightstone](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Sightstone) seems like a fantastic value,

> Unique: Ghost Ward - Consumes a charge to place a  Ghost Ward. **You may have a maximum of 2 wards from this item at once.**

What happens when you put down a third ward while two are still on the map?

Does the same happen with the [Ruby Sightstone](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ruby_Sightstone)?

Comment: I believe that appears an error message saying that you already have 2 wards. And the same should occur with both Ruby and normal sightstones.

Comment: ERRATUM: in the first comment it says "I just thought of something hilarious: when some support with oracles tries to destroy the first ward you dropped, drop a new ward, and the old one will disappear without giving them gold :D" ***So, they disappear.***

Comment: Sightstone is easily the best item to have as a support this season

Comment: @Paralytic until you need to have more than 2/3 out at once :P

Comment: @Brian a support should really only have to put 3 wards out at once, top and jungle should be helping to ward atleast a tad

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It deletes the oldest ghost ward out at the time and places your new one down. See below for examples

[image: Two wards]

Here is two wards from the sight stone

[image: Third ward]

You can see the other ward fading out after I placed the third

[image: Third ward with ruby]

After getting the ruby sight stone I can place a third ward with the other two out

[image]

However trying to place a fourth ward causing the oldest to disappear still

Comment: And no error is given either.

Comment: This matches what I've heard elsewhere too. Could you provide a source or a screenshot just for clarity?

Comment: Sure when I get home from work I'll go into a custom game (If they let me) to screen cap or replay it.